# Can not run even Microsoft security essentials- Windows 7

Tags: anti-virus, ms-security-essentials

I have windows 7 64 bit running in my computer and i have been using Microsoft security essentials as my antivirus.It was running fine and yesterday when i was trying to do a system scan, It found that its not working.ie: when i start the service, the IDE comes and stay for 1 -2 seconds and then disappears. I went to System tray and found the icon for MSE. But when i move my cursor to the area where the icons are present, the MSE icon disappears !

I did system restore. I un-installed MSE and reinstalled it again. I ran windows update to make sure that i have the latest patches. But still no luck with that. I m infected badly it looks like. Cant run the antivirus even.

What to do now ? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: See mt post in this wiki...http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware/157533#157533

Answer (score 1):

If it's really infected, you may need to wipe and reinstall. Backups?

To even confirm that's the problem you could try running Housecall from housecall.trendmicro.com or running a free antivirus to confirm it's an infection and not corruption, but again if you strongly suspect you're infected you shouldn't even be using that computer as you don't know what it's sending out or receiving from the Internet. It could be spamming people or running as part of a denial of service attack on someone without your knowledge.

Me, I'd want to confirm that's the problem by running a check with the Ultimate Boot CD's disk diagnostics and running a thorough chkdsk on the drive to makes sure there's nothing weird going on. Then I'd try running antivirus checks, from housecall and if that failed perhaps another antivirus (preferably an *offline* scanner, one that boots from disc and runs independent of the installed operating system so if there IS malware on it it's not spamming and circumventing detection. In the end, though, chances are the answer is format and reinstall and recover from *known good backups.*